# Encontro (Festa de Graduação) da comunidade SOpt 4.0 (Portugal)

Tags: debate, meetup

## Conta-me como foi...

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Na foto, da esquerda para a direita @Zuul, @JorgeB., @Omni e @jsantos1991.

Encontra-mo-nos por volta das 21 horas em Coimbra. Claro que um dos principais focos da nossa conversa foi a eleição em curso (a minha campanha não parece ter corrido muito bem :P ). Deu para nos conhecer-mos um pouco e falar sobre a nossa área em geral, ah e para comer-mos muito bem também :D

No meu ponto de vista foi bastante produtivo, conhecemos melhor as pessoas que nos respondem as perguntas diariamente e conseguimos saber a opinião de cada um sobre o site e o que se poderia melhorar.

Acho que devíamos marcar outro em breve.

Nota: Ao ir embora, com o @jsantos1991, ao ir meter gasolina o meu carro fechou-se com a chave dentro e uma pessoa que estava lá conseguiu abrir com uma navalha. ;)

Os presentes no evento sintam-se a vontade de editar e dizer mais alguma coisa que me tenha esquecido.

---

## Encontro SOpt 4.0

Depois de tantos encontros da comunidade do [Stackoverflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) no Brasil, agora é a hora de fazer um encontro em Portugal, não acham?

Abri aqui este post para ver a reação dos utilizadores do SOpt a um encontro em Portugal. <strike>Reparem que meti a localização para [Braga](https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Braga,+Portugal/@41.5472749,-8.4114212,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0xd24febc6cf5d867:0xbc5d054162d1e218) porque é a cidade em que mais facilmente consigo arranjar condições para o encontro. Mas podemos ver qualquer alternativa que vos pareça melhor. Data também a definir.</strike>

**Sendo assim queria saber qual é a vossa disponibilidade para este evento!**

E não se esqueçam que as tasquinhas<sup>1</sup> com boa comida e um bom vinho também não faltam, eu conheço umas quantas :)

1 - Imagem duma tasquinha típica Portuguesa.
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

#### Edição

<strike>Eu queria marcar um dia e local para o evento mas para já só estamos 3 pessoas, o que é muito pouco, Não há mais nenhum Portuga por ai? Ou alguém que queira dar cá um salto?</strike>

Para já estamos 7 se não me enganei a fazer as contas, acho que vale a pena esperar mais uns dias a ver se aparece mais alguém distraído... O local que mais agrada a todos é no centro do país.

Sítios sugeridos:

- <strike>[Braga](https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Braga,+Portugal/@41.5472749,-8.4114212,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0xd24febc6cf5d867:0xbc5d054162d1e218) **||**</strike>
- [Coimbra (ou Mealhada é próximo)](https://www.google.pt/maps/place/Coimbra/@40.282065,-8.4244806,11z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0xd22f8c2c7cbeeb7:0x400ebbde49031d0) **|||||**

Interessados:

- Omni
- jsantos1991
- chambelix
- ramaral
- Ninita
- Filipe Moraes
- Jorge B.

Comment: Temos que organizar um encontro aqui no Brasil p/ eu participar também... mais especificamente no sul do Brasil... mais detalhadamente no Paraná, de preferencia na minha cidade aqui em Foz do Iguaçu rsrssr

Comment: A melhor parte (para quem não estava lá) foi a do carro com a chave trancada dentro :)

Comment: *"Carro trancado com a chave dentro"*? Pois, devem ter *só* comido muito bem!

Comment: @ramaral o carro fechou-se sozinho quando eu fechei a porta lol

Comment: putz, perdi esta! Quando passar perto da fronteira, prometo dar um pulo na Tasca :)

Comment: @brasofilo temos de marcar outra :p

Comment: @JorgeB.: demorou! Um lugar q gostaria de voltar é Porto Gaia, achei bonito d+ :)

Comment: @brasofilo podemos marcar um no Porto a ver se o povo adere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Local do encontro: [Cantinho dos Reis](https://goo.gl/maps/czRtZ)

Data: 19 de Junho de 2015

Horas: 21h

Notas: Há estacionamento ao lado do restaurante ou se preferirem ficar mais perto da praça o [estacionamento do mercado abastecedor](https://goo.gl/maps/Yfg40) fica perto e salvo erro continua a ser de graça depois das 20h.

---

Não poderia existir melhor altura para fazer este evento, o SOpt foi graduado e nós podemos festejar em primeira mão a graduação :)
As outras comunidades de língua portuguesa que se queiram juntar a festa é só comprarem o bilhete para cá ;)

---

Como dito na pergunta as seguintes pessoas demonstraram interesse no encontro:

- Omni ✓
- jsantos1991 ✓
- <strike>chambelix</strike>
- <strike>ramaral</strike>
- <strike>Ninita</strike>
- <strike>Filipe Moraes</strike>
- Jorge B. ✓
- Zuul ✓

Pedia aos mencionados que confirmassem se vão. E se mais alguém quiser vir, diga nos comentários e eu adiciono aqui o nome :D

#rumoao4encontrosopt